# long ajax call blocks the browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I have a long ajax call fired in my html template. I'm using jquery, here is the call :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('my_action') }}",
        data: { datas : {
                   id: '{{ new.id }}'
              }}                                        
    });     
});     
</script>
```

The process behind this call is long and can take several minutes. I don't want to care about it while it's processing, i just want to get the response back, even if i have left the page. So i bind the global ajax event like this :

```
<script>
$(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", function(event, xhr){
    alert('ok');
});
</script>
```

All is working fine BUT, after the ajax call, i can't do anything. If i want to click a link to go to another page, or if i want to go back, the browser is waiting and nothing happen untill the ajax request is done. Why ? Ajax is asynchronous and should'nt block the browser. Any idea ?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous to the client side (or at least it should be).  It needs to complete the task before you leave the page.  For very long tasks Ajax is generally not the answer.  Instead use AMQP, Gearman or just plain background processes to shake of the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Between RabbitMQ and Gearman, which one would you recommand to me (i'm using symfony2)

Comment: Gearman is preferred for off-loading tasks.  They can be listened to to receive feedback (so can MQ).  AMQP is preferred for agnostic listeners, like cross site events opposed to RPC.

Answer (score 1):

Using Gearman, you can call one synchronous job which gives an initial status and performs some light IO.  This job may trigger another asynchronous job and return the job ID to you.

You can then track this asynchronous jobs status: http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php

For the browser, polling via Ajax might still be necessary to communicate with a PHP script which in turn retrieves Gearman's status (and progress).